# Recall a class from another class

Tags: java, actionlistener

Hello I made a die in Java ( very simple ) and now when I start the app I get a very nice die with a random value between 1 and 6, the only thing that does not work is my button to throw again ( like the class is not recalled or something ) and I hope someone can tell me what I've done wrong. Below you can find my 2 classes

throwbutton action class:

```
package h05Dobbelsteen;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Worp extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JButton worp;

DobbelSteen dobbelsteen;

public Worp() {

    dobbelsteen = new DobbelSteen();
    worp = new JButton("Werp de dobbelsteen");
    worp.addActionListener(this);

    add(worp);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    dobbelsteen.roll();

}

}
```

and my die class is as follows

```
package h05Dobbelsteen;
```

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DobbelSteen extends JPanel {

```
private final static int SPOT_DIAMETER = 40; // diameter dobbelsteen rondjes
private int faceValue; // getoonde waarde op scherm

public DobbelSteen() {

    roll();

}

/*
 * roll de dobbelsteen
 */
public int roll() {

    int val = (int) (6*Math.random() + 1); // bepaal getal tussen 1 - 6
    setValue(val);
    return val;

}

/*
 * set de waarde van de roll
 */
public void setValue(int spots) {
    faceValue = spots;
    repaint();
}

/*
 * get de waarde van de roll
 */
public int getValue() {
    return faceValue;
}

/*
 * teken de view van de dobbelsteen
 */
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    int w = getWidth();  // Get height and width
    int h = getHeight();

    // Graphics naar 2d
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    //... Paint background
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g2.drawRect(0, 0, w-1, h-1);  // Draw border

    switch (faceValue) {
        case 1:
            drawSpot(g2, w/2, h/2);
            break;
        case 3:
            drawSpot(g2, w/2, h/2);

        case 2:
            drawSpot(g2, w/4, h/4);
            drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
            break;
        case 5:
            drawSpot(g2, w/2, h/2);
        case 4:
            drawSpot(g2, w/4, h/4);
            drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
            drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, h/4);
            drawSpot(g2, w/4, 3*h/4);
            break;
        case 6:
            drawSpot(g2, w/4, h/4);
            drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
            drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, h/4);
            drawSpot(g2, w/4, 3*h/4);
            drawSpot(g2, w/4, h/2);
            drawSpot(g2, 3*w/4, h/2);
            break;
    }
}

/*
 * Teken de spots
 */
private void drawSpot(Graphics2D g2, int x, int y) {
    g2.fillOval(x-SPOT_DIAMETER/2, y-SPOT_DIAMETER/2, SPOT_DIAMETER, SPOT_DIAMETER);
}
```

}

JFrame class

```
package h05Dobbelsteen;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

public class startDobbelsteen {

JFrame frame = null;

public startDobbelsteen() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setTitle("Dobbelsteen");
    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 450, 450);

    DobbelSteen dobbelsteen = new DobbelSteen();
    frame.add(dobbelsteen, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Worp worp = new Worp();
    frame.add(worp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program is not complete (no main method, no JFrame), but you don't have any DobbelSteen instance *displayed* in this program. The DobbelSteen rolled by the displayed button (`worp`)  is never added to any panel, so rolling it won't change anything in the appearance of the application.

Comment: The main method and Jframe etc are in a seperate class but i didn't post them because the code was not relevant in my opinion, for the second part.. do i have to give worp to the constructor of DobbelSteen?

Comment: No. Why would you have to? The main method and JFrame are probably relevant. If you see a die on your screen, it's another instance, created and added elsewhere, than the one rolled by the worp button. To make it even clearer: you have two dies: one is a visible die that never changes, and the other, invisible one, is the one rolled by the worp button.

Comment: I have added the JFrame class. At this moment the constructor of DobbelSteen creates the first throw when the program launches so in fact I have to re-start the constructor with the help of the button right? or is that overkill? ( p.s. with system.out.println(val) I see the value of dice being changed every time but i get nothing on the screen)

Comment: Objects in Java are like real objects. You have two calls to `new Dobbelsteen()` in your program. This means that you created two different dies. One of the dies is created and displayed by the main frame. The other one is created by the Worp panel, never displayed, but rolled by the worp button. That's like having two dies: one on the table, and one in a closed box. If you shake the box, the die in the box will change its face value, but the one on the table will stay unmodified. You must create **one** die, and pass this die to the Worp panel, so that the worp button rolls the displayed die

Comment: ah that makes clear on and other! I think I understand my mistake now and I think i can solve the problem thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    DobbelSteen dobbelsteen;

    public Worp(DobbelSteen ds) {

        dobbelsteen = ds;
        worp = new JButton("Werp de dobbelsteen");
       worp.addActionListener(this);

        add(worp);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        dobbelsteen.roll();

    }

    }
```

You can try this. In your JFrame class constructor make one DobbelSteen and add it to the container. Then do Worp worp = new Worp(dobbelsteenNaam); and add worp also to the container. I'm not sure though if your repaint() call is in the right place.